# Booking class - China Airlines

Tags: bookings, skyteam, china-airlines

Based on my boarding ticket, is my booking class E or Y? How do I know?  It obviously seems to be Y but a customer service representative said it was E and am seeking retro mileage claim.

[image]

Other info----
The Korean Air service rep isn't giving me my mileage (via flight partners on Sky Team) cause they claim its E booking class.  Can I call China Air to verify my booking class?
Is there a definitive answer about what booking class I really have?

These are the mileage accrual rules based on the A, B, C, D whatever booking class
https://www.koreanair.com/global/en/skypass/earn/partner-ailrlines/china-airlines/

The receipt is from my booking it on a Chinese website (ctrip.com) and it just translates to "economy" class without stating the letter

Comment: Its quite obvious to me (and I'm not talking about the watermark Y outline) that its a Y class (`CI0003 **Y** 05NOV 333`); I'm not sure why the CS rep told you E.

Comment: I'd file for frequent flyer points using Y class, and then if that fails, use E ;)

Comment: FINAL ANSWER:  I called China Airlines, they said cause I bought a discount/cheap ticket (on ctrip.com which is like a Chinese Expedia) the booking class is L.  Larry.  There is no way I could have determined that just from looking at the ticket.  Sadly, L Booking class Economy Cabin ticket do not even qualify for China Airline's own mileage program, much less a Sky Team member's like Korean Air.  MORAL OF THE STORY:  If you want an airline's frequent flyer mileage, look at the booking class online under fare rules and regulations BEFORE paying.

Comment: Its pretty dumb I can't even accumulate China Airline miles through its own mileage program on a China Air flight. Who invented this policy!!?? If I knew this first I would have just paid like 100 dollars more and bought it on the China Air website for a normal ticket/booking class and thus being able to earn my miles....http://www.china-airlines.com/en/club/club_mi_3.htm

Answer (score 2):

The "Y" printed between the flight number and date, may simply refer to the cabin. There is no rule that requires displaying the fare code, many systems simply put Y or COACH to indicate the cabin you are sitting in, while others actually put the fare bucket C, K, M, etc.

The key to your fare class is in your fare basis, which maybe printed on your receipt.  Normally the first letter of the fare basis is your booking class (your image doesn't show the entirety of the receipt).

Actually on your boarding pass, just above the etkt number is what could be your fare basis or it could be your PNR (reservation identifier).  If it is your fare basis, then you are in K class, which is a discounted excursion fare, hence her reference to an "E" class.  If it is your PNR ignore the previous words ;-)

Comment: (PNR = Passenger Name Record for anyone else who wondered)

Comment: @MarkMayo - also synonymous with the word "Booking", for passenger purposes. Tom - Y IS a fare code, not a cabin, there's no such thing as "Y Cabin" - there are simply fare codes which belong to Coach/Economy/Economy+/Club/Business/First etc. I've never seen an airline print a ticket with a "representative" cabin class related-to-but-not-the-same-as the fare code.

Comment: Jon - plenty of airline boarding passes refer to the economy cabin as Y.  I have had several in the past year, where my actual fare class was not shown and Y was.  Y serves as both the universal economy cabin indicator, as well as full fare economy class on most airlines.